Search in Telegram export data in python
I have result.json - saved data from Telegram. how do I find a message containing a specific text and messages by id?
code:
import json

with open('result.json', encoding="utf8") as f:
    msgs = json.load(f)

for reply_to_message_id, text in msgs.items():
    if 'sometext' in text:
        print(text)
        print(reply_message_id)


doesn't work

doesn't work please be more lucid in describing result. Did you get any error? No output at all? Yet something else?

This question is similar to: Python: Loop through JSON File. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i think this should work better:
import json

with open('result.json', encoding="utf8") as f:
    msgs = json.load(f)

for message in msgs:
    if 'sometext' in message.get('text', ''):
        print(f"ID: {message['message_id']}, Text: {message['text']}")

Just ensure your result.json is a list of messages with keys like message_id and text. If the structure is different, adjust accordingly.

What is 'text' in message. Get ?

'text' is the key that holds the message content. in: message.get('text', '') gets it, or returns an empty string.
if im wrong or  something which i dont think pls correct me.
